# How to change Labels colors on a donut chart using nvd3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How can I make the labels have the same color of each slice on donut chart using nvd3?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxj5i.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802750/how-to-change-color-of-donut-chart-created-using-d3-js

Comment: no, it's not. I figure out how to change the slice color, but not how to change the label color

Comment: does this other one helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874877/how-do-i-color-labels-for-my-pie-chart-in-d3

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, will try :D

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
var colors = ["#eb5945", "#f8e71c", "#67c60b"];
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
  .x(function(d) { return d.label })
  .y(function(d) { return d.value })
  .showLabels(true)
  .showLegend(false)
  .labelThreshold(.05)
  .tooltips(false)
  .color(colors)
  .donutLabelsOutside(true)  
  .donut(true)
  .donutRatio(0.7);

    d3.select("#chart svg")
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .call(chart);

    d3.selectAll('.nv-label text')
      .each(function(d,i){
        d3.select(this).style('fill',colors[i])
        d3.select(this).style('font-weight', 700)
        d3.select(this).style('font-size', 16)
    })

  return chart;
});
```